# Prevent multiple clicks on add to cart button - wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to know what is the best way to prevent double click on add to cart button in wordpress. At the moment I can click on the addto cart multiple times and as the product only allows a quantity of 1, the cart page states that a product already exists in the cart, when it reality it's because of the double click.

I tried the code below but did not work as it still allows multiple clicks:

```
do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item');

function onlyonce(){ ?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.cart').one('submit', function() {
$(this).find('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
});

</script>
<?php }
```

[image]

Comment: maybe you can disable the button on `click` instead of on `submit` ?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is to disable the button on `click` instead of on `submit`.

Let me know if the code below helps.

*Mods* The code is only as a guide, I will delete the answer once OP confirms this helps or not.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#submitBtn').on('click', function() {
    console.log('disabling');
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    console.log('disabled');

    // then submit your form
  });
  /*
    $('.cart').one('submit', function() {
      $(this).find('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
    */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="submitBtn" type="submit">Checkout</button>
```

Comment: Hmmm... didn't seem to work. Also wondering if this will affect all add to cart buttons as it's a class? .add_to_cart_button. Basically I did same as your code but used my class rather than the id of submitBtn

Comment: If there are more than one button with the same class name, it will affect all of them (and the syntax is a bit different) - you need to use the id of the button or a different (but very specific) selector

Comment: Yeah I think the issue is that its a woo commerce theme so they geenrate buttons as classes with same name

Comment: You can just add `$(this).attr('disabled', true)` inside the click callback which will only disabled the button that was clicked

Comment: @JoshBonnick the code will still affect all buttons with the same class when *those* are clicked - this might not be desireable

Comment: @BruceyBandit does the form (or any parent element) have an `id` ? you can always adjust the selector to be something like `$('#formId button[type="sumbit"]').on('click', ...);`

Comment: https://codepen.io/josh-unit36/pen/bGegWEo

Comment: @JoshBonnick I am not sure what you are trying to prove.  What if one wanted to disable only one of those two buttons (in your code) ?

Comment: The original question was to limit add to cart buttons to one click. The snippet I provided disabled the add to cart button once clicked.

Comment: @JoshBonnick So does my code ;) - the point I am trying to make is that if he has more than one button with the same class name and OP *does not* want those to be disabled once clicked, he would have to use a more specific selector.

Comment: @JoshBonnick if however, he wants to apply the same behaviour to all buttons with the same class, then OP can use the snippet of code you or I provided :)

Comment: @BruceyBandit to answer you concern, yes it will apply to all buttons with the same class `.add_to_cart_button` on the same page

Comment: @blurfus I added a screenshot to help. I believe I may have to use the data-product-id and then have to refer to each one individually. But the code currently doesn't disable. Plus the issue is if I disable the button and then user removes product from cart, can it enable again? At the moment the button text changes from 'Add to cart' to 'Already in cart'. Let me explain the situation further...

Comment: So if the user doesn't have the product in their cart. If they click the add to cart button, it will take them to the cart page and show the product in the cart. This is great. Now here is the situation. Remove the product from the cart so we start again...

Comment: Now if I click on the add to cart button for the product mutlple times, it doesn't redirect me to the cart page. The button text does change so it doesn't say add to cart, it now says already in cart' and I can see in the shopping icon top right that it has updated the cart, it just doesn't redirect me to the cart. So that's why I thought prevent double click so after one click, it takes user to cart. But... if I do have this text change, does it really matter as user can see the button change from 'add to cart' to already in cart'?

Comment: @BruceyBandit you are describing an entire workflow beyond the scope of the original question.  You need to keep track of which items you have in the cart and which are not and then update the button accordingly.

Comment: @BruceyBandit also, the screenshot shows only an anchor tag (`<a href="..">...</a>`) instead of a button - is this what you are trying to disable? (buttons and anchor behave differently)

Comment: You can also close google chrome tabs if you wanted to :D

Comment: @JoshBonnick Yeah I am terrible with tabs lol

Comment: @blurufs yeah this is how the add to cart button is done through woocommerce, via link. Yeah it's a good point and something I did not relaise that it's a link and not a button. But still, the idea is to register only the first click and not the clicks after (as in if they click quickly multiple times, don't register those, just register the first click)